# How to put address in the same level?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}





\begin{flushleft}                           
\textbf{Riyam Sen} \\
 Department of Mathematical Sciences, Aligarh University \\
Napaam, Sonitpur, Delhi-110025, India. \\
e-mail:  ri45.das@gmail.com 
\end{flushleft}


\begin{flushright} 
\textbf{Pronoy Pratim Dutta} \\
 Statistics and Mathematics Unit, Indian Statistical Institute,\\ 
Bangalore, R. V. College Post, Bangalore 560059,
India. \\
e-mail:  brijk5897@gmail.com 
\end{flushright} 

\end{document}
```

In this code I am trying to put the name and addresses in the same level .But one is little  up and one is little down.

How we can put them in the same level?

Comment: There's nothing about `biblatex` in the code, so this needs to be retagged.  The final text shouldn't be formatted as code, but it's unclear to me how this was formatted, so an attempt to fix it failed.  What I *think* you want is to put two addresses side by side.  To do that, put each address in a `minipage` with a width of `.45\textwidth`, get rid of the blank line that separates them and replace it by `\hfil`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a user friendly "programming" interface i would suggest you to use the `tcolorbox` package for tasks like this.

The following example is a good starting point.

(Maybe i have to much fantasy but i guess you are looking for something like this)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newtcolorbox{heading}{%
    blankest, 
    sidebyside, 
    enlarge left by  = -1cm,
    enlarge right by = 2cm,
    width            = \linewidth+2cm,
    halign lower     = flush right,
    after            = \bigskip\bigskip,
    top              = 4mm,
    bottom           = 4mm,
    sidebyside align = top seam,
    borderline north = {1.8pt}{0pt}{black},
    borderline south = {1.0pt}{0pt}{black}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{heading}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \textbf{Riyam Sen} \\
        Department of Mathematical Sciences, Aligarh University \\
        Napaam, Sonitpur, Delhi-110025, India. \\
        e-mail:  ri45.das@gmail.com 
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \tcblower
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \textbf{Pronoy Pratim Dutta} \\
        Statistics and Mathematics Unit\\
        Indian Statistical Institute\\ 
        Bangalore, R. V. College Post\\
        Bangalore 560059 India \\
        e-mail:  brijk5897@gmail.com 
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{heading}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```